# RecursiveDirectoryIterator in PHP, getting each directory twice in foreach

Tags: php, iterator, php-5.5, spl

I have the following very simple RecursiveDirectoryIterator code:

```
$dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('/Users/yivi/test/',  RecursiveDirectoryIterator::KEY_AS_PATHNAME);

$iter = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir);

foreach ($iter as $item) {
  if ($item->isDir()) {
      echo $item->getPath() . "\n";
      $countd ++;
  } else {
      $count++;
  }
}
echo "$count files and $count directories";
```

But produces the following output:

```
/Users/yivi/Sites/test
/Users/yivi/Sites/test
/Users/yivi/Sites/test/01
/Users/yivi/Sites/test/01
/Users/yivi/Sites/test/02
/Users/yivi/Sites/test/02
/Users/yivi/Sites/test/03
/Users/yivi/Sites/test/03
/Users/yivi/Sites/test/03/ab
/Users/yivi/Sites/test/03/ab
/Users/yivi/Sites/test/03/cd
/Users/yivi/Sites/test/03/cd

40 files and 12 directories
```

By the time I exit the loop I counted each directory twice (I get the double listing and $countd is 12, instead of 6).

Why is it behaving this way? How to avoid it?

I've tried using `RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS` as a flag, but then it skips all directories (but does count the files).

(PHP 5.5)

Comment: I personally don't know how to fix it at the core of the class, but to get around it (if you are in a hurry) is output to an array then `array_unique()`

Comment: Yup, and I can think of other quick fixes as well, but mostly I would like to understand this behavior. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Yeah, I hear you. I have run into weird behaviors like this with the iterators and I just fix them quick and dirty, so I am also interested how to fix this particular behavior at the class level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** Use `RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST` as the iteration mode, along with the `RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS` flag.

---

You are seeing two lines because the `$item` values are for the "." and ".." items, and were right to try using `SKIP_DOTS` as you most likely do want to skip those items.

However, the default behaviour for the `RecursiveIteratorIterator` is to only iterate over "leaf" items (i.e, items that don't contain more items) rather than everything, effectively skipping the directories.

So, you need to tell `RecursiveIteratorIterator` use a different mode, other than the default "leaves only" mode: one of "self first" or "child first".

```
$iter = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
```

---

Back to your original code, you can see what's going on by echoing `$item->getPathname()` (or simply echoing `$item` would work here).  That would show you the "dot directories" that you need to skip.